# Name generation from human rules

Tags: machine-learning, generator

I'm looking for a solution that allow me to generate name from non official/known/written rules.

Here are several example :

- Mairie de Paris -> MPARIS
- Mairie de Saint Etienne -> MSTETIENNE
- Transport Dupont -> DUPONTTRANSPORT
- Lycée Louis Barthou -> LLouisBarthou

I was initialy thinking about machine learning, but I have no clue to start with it.

Thanks you very much

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) apply here.
StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial service.

Answer (score 0):

## Although its quite random but you can try the following function and edit it to your will.

```
import random
from nltk import word_tokenize

def generate_name(s):
    s_tokenized = word_tokenize(s)
    stop_words= ['de']
    s_tokenized_list = []
    for w in s_tokenized:
        if w not in stop_words:
            s_tokenized_list.append(w)
    name=[]
    length_of_list = len(s_tokenized_list)
    if length_of_list>=3:
        for n in s_tokenized_list[:length_of_list-1]:
            name.append(n[0])
    elif length_of_list==2:
        for n in s_tokenized_list[:length_of_list-1]:
            name.append(n[0])
    name= ''.join(name)
    return ''.join(name+s_tokenized_list[length_of_list-1].upper())
```